# Flow deployment error in Copado "you must specify a record filter or a formula"

Tags: visual-workflow, deployment

I have a very simple Record Triggered flow.
When deploying a flow using Copado I am getting an error

```
Because All Conditions are Met or Any Conditions are Met is specified, you must specify a record filter or a formula
```

This is my configuration page. There is no Entry Condition

[image]

This is the criteria at the Decision Node

[image]

I am not sure where what record filter or formula I need to specify and where ?

Can someone help me in understanding this specific deployment error?

Comment: if you can deploy the Flow via a changeset, then it is a Copado bug

Comment: also check what api version is being used to retrieve & deploy. This is a feature (use formulas as flow entry conditions) that is new for Summer '22. Sharing the metadata of the flow would help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SumitKumar I deleted the flow and rebuilt a new flow without formula and deployed. Fortunately for me I could use basic criteria instead of formula.

However at least 4 other folks working on other projects encoutered this issue. Some of the resolutions are as follows

1. Deploying through Change set is fine
2. Copado is still on Metadata version 54, they're not switching to v55 until next week. Updating the API version in the project level sfdx-project.json file seems to have done the trick
3. it work when you use sfdx and specify the version as 55 in your package.xml when retrieving and deploying

Hope this helps.